# BizTalk can comunicate with COM/DCOM?

Tags: com, biztalk

I need to make Biztalk exchange data with an OPC A&E server, and it uses COM communication, so I'd like to know if I need to develop some kind of adapter or there's a direct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have integrated with DCOM services from BizTalk by running .net code called from an orchestration.

For example:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

string serverName = "My Server";
string progID = "My DCOM ProgID";
Type objType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID, serverName, true);
object objLateBound = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
```